# How do I create a new instance of a Angular component when testing?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I thought the tests were independent of each other. And the function creates a new instance for each test. But it turns out that the component is instantiated once and used in all tests.
I have a list that gets populated during component initialization. In one test, I called a function - the list was full. In another test, I wanted to change the initial conditions and re-initialize the component. But I saw in debugging that even before the second initialization, the list is not empty, but after initialization, accordingly, it has duplicates

```
describe('TerritoryComponent', () => {
  let component: TerritoryComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TerritoryComponent>;
  let territoryApiService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ TerritoryComponent ],
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TerritoryComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

it('tets1', () => {
    //territoriesList contains only 1 item (default)
    component.ngOnInit();
    //territoriesList already contains 3 items
    expect(component.territoriesList.length).toBe(3);
  })

it('test2', () => {
    component.isWait = false;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    //territoriesList already contains 3 items
    component.ngOnInit();
    //territoriesList already contains 5 items
    expect(component.territoriesList.length).toBe(3); //Error: Expected 5 to be 3.
  });
});
```

Is it possible to make another test have a new component instance with default values? Can you combine fixture2.detectChanges() with component.ngOnInit()?
Instantiating the component inside the test didn't help

```
it('test2', () => {
  let fixture2 = TestBed.createComponent(TerritoryComponent);
  let component2 = fixture2.componentInstance;
  component2.isWait = false;
  fixture2.detectChanges();
  //territoriesList already contains 3 items
  component2.ngOnInit();
  //territoriesList already contains 5 items
  expect(component2.territoriesList.length).toBe(3); //Error: Expected 5 to be 3.
});
```

Resetting 'fixture' didn't help either

```
afterEach(() => {
    fixture.destroy();
  });
```

Here is the simplified code of my component for which I am creating tests:

```
export class TerritoryComponent implements OnInit {
public territoriesList: Territory[];

constructor(...) {
  this.territoriesList = [];
}

  ngOnInit() {
     this.GetTerritories();
  }

    public GetTerritories(): void {
    var filter: requestForFilter = 
    this.reportService.CreateFilterForRequest();
    this.territoryApiService.GetFiltered(filter).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.FillTerritoriesList(data);
      }
    );
  }

  private FillTerritoriesList(territories: Territory[]) {
    if (territories.length > 0) {
      for (let territory of territories) {
        this.territoriesList.push(territory);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: they are independent. In your tests component is getting created in `beforeEach`, so it will be created before each test. maybe you have strange component logic, that persists data between component creations?

Comment: A simple component that in ngOnInit makes a request to a remote server and stores the received data in a local list. It's all about fixture.detectChanges (). The component has default values before it is called. But as soon as I call fixture.detectChanges (), then the component becomes with the value from the previous test.

Comment: sounds weird. could you please provide your component onInit code? `fixture.detectChanges()` just calls change detection. i.e. it will call ngOnInit() hook for your component if you call detecChanges() the first time after component creation. you shouldn't call ngOnInit() yourself

Comment: **Andrei**, if you suggest doing `fixture.detectChanges()` at the very beginning, which will call `ngOnInit()`, then how can I test the data before initialization?

Comment: Call it after data is set up.

Comment: **Andrei**, please tell me, how should I test the input, for example?
`nameInput [2] .value = 'TerritoryTest1';
nameInput [2] .dispatchEvent (new Event ('input'));`
There you need to call `fixture.detectChanges()` again. Then I get the values from the previous test again

Comment: In runtime user inputs happen after initialization. So dispatching input ilshould be done after first detect changes, but you can detect changes multiple times during one trst

Comment: **Andrei**, maybe then today or tomorrow I will prepare an example in stackblitz / plunker, and then you will watch it?

Comment: Do you really need more help, after you got the point?

Comment: When you call detectChanges, ngOnInit is invoked (for the first and last time, BTW). And that is why your list contains 3 items.

Comment: One moment I did not fully understand: how to check the data before initialization.
If I make this setting
`beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TerritoryComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
})`, 
then If I do this, this test will fail, because the data has already changed after initialization (the length of the list will become 3)
`it('test1', () => {
    expect(component.territoriesList.length).toBe(0);
})`

Comment: Is your component actually getting the data from a live server in your test, or is it getting it from a mock? If it's getting it from a mock, it's useful to use some form of cloning (lodash's `cloneDeep` for example), because otherwise all your tests will reference the same object in memory.   This is probably way late for the problem you are dealing with here, but might help someone else that finds this question.